# How to add a full URL as an endpoint to a GET request

Tags: php, symfony, routes, get

I'm trying to make a GET request and add a full url a a variable like so

```
     * @Route("/foobar/{url}", name="foobar", methods={"GET"})
```

When i however try to call this in postman

```
http://foo.bar.local/post/https://www.google.de/
```

I get

```
   No route found for "GET /foobar/https://www.google.de/"
```

However if i do anything else, for example

```
1
www.google.de
```

I get the correct response

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a requirements on your route annotation like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/url-test/{url}", name="url_test", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"url"=".+"})
 */
public function url_test($url)
{
    dump($url); // https://www.google.de/
}
```

And to check I use the url : https://127.0.0.1:8000/url-test/https://www.google.de/

Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/routing/slash_in_parameter.html

Comment: Hey when i add that requirement i get: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: But again if i use just a normal www. or any number it works.

Comment: I just tested it on a Symfony 5 application, and it worked for me...
Can you verify if your route does not conflict with another one ? If you use a Symfony 5.1+ app, you can use the `priority` parameter too.

Comment: Can you maybe post your example, it does not work for me.

Comment: @roibubble I just edited my answer with a bit more infos

Comment: Hello can you maybe try wit this url ? https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.de

Comment: @roibubble, just tested it - it's working too on my side. Maybe try it on a fresh install of Symfony?

Comment: When i try with a  encoded url, i get a server error....